# Resulting .exe from PyInstaller with wxPython crashing

Tags: python, wxpython, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile a very simple wxPython script into an executable by using PyInstaller on Windows Vista.

The Python script is nothing but a Hello World in wxPython. I'm trying to get that up and running as a Windows executable before I add any of the features that the program needs to have. But I'm already stuck.

I've jumped through some loops in regards to MSVCR90.DLL, MSVCP90.DLL and MSVCPM90.DLL, which I ended up copying from my Visual Studio installation (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT).

As according to the instructions for PyInstaller, I run:

```
Command:
Configure.py

Output:
I: computing EXE_dependencies
I: Finding TCL/TK...
I: could not find TCL/TK
I: testing for Zlib...
I: ... Zlib available
I: Testing for ability to set icons, version resources...
I: ... resource update available
I: Testing for Unicode support...
I: ... Unicode available
I: testing for UPX...
I: ...UPX available
I: computing PYZ dependencies...
```

So far, so good. I continue.

```
Command:
Makespec.py -F guitest.py

Output:
wrote C:\Code\PromoUSB\guitest.spec
now run Build.py to build the executable
```

Then there's the final command.

```
Command:
Build.py guitest.spec

Output:
checking Analysis
building Analysis because out0.toc non existent
running Analysis out0.toc
Analyzing: C:\Python26\pyinstaller-1.3\support\_mountzlib.py
Analyzing: C:\Python26\pyinstaller-1.3\support\useUnicode.py
Analyzing: guitest.py
Warnings written to C:\Code\PromoUSB\warnguitest.txt
checking PYZ
rebuilding out1.toc because out1.pyz is missing
building PYZ out1.toc
checking PKG
rebuilding out3.toc because out3.pkg is missing
building PKG out3.pkg
checking ELFEXE
rebuilding out2.toc because guitest.exe missing
building ELFEXE out2.toc
```

I get the resulting 'guitest.exe' file, but upon execution, it "simply crashes"... and there is no debug info. It's just one of those standard Windows Vista crashes.

The script itself, guitest.py runs just fine by itself. It only crashes as an executable, and I'm completely lost. I don't even know what to look for, since nothing I've tried has returned any relevant results.

Another file is generated as a result of the compilation process, called 'warnguitest.txt'. Here are its contents.

```
W: no module named posix (conditional import by os)
W: no module named optik.__all__ (top-level import by optparse)
W: no module named readline (delayed, conditional import by cmd)
W: no module named readline (delayed import by pdb)
W: no module named pwd (delayed, conditional import by posixpath)
W: no module named org (top-level import by pickle)
W: no module named posix (delayed, conditional import by iu)
W: no module named fcntl (conditional import by subprocess)
W: no module named org (top-level import by copy)
W: no module named _emx_link (conditional import by os)
W: no module named optik.__version__ (top-level import by optparse)
W: no module named fcntl (top-level import by tempfile)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - collections (C:\Python26\lib\collections.pyc)
W: delayed  exec statement detected at line 0 - collections (C:\Python26\lib\collections.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - doctest (C:\Python26\lib\doctest.pyc)
W: delayed  exec statement detected at line 0 - doctest (C:\Python26\lib\doctest.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - doctest (C:\Python26\lib\doctest.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - encodings (C:\Python26\lib\encodings\__init__.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - optparse (C:\Python26\pyinstaller-1.3\optparse.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - dis (C:\Python26\lib\dis.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - os (C:\Python26\lib\os.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - __future__ (C:\Python26\lib\__future__.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - unittest (C:\Python26\lib\unittest.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - unittest (C:\Python26\lib\unittest.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - tokenize (C:\Python26\lib\tokenize.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - wx (C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\__init__.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - wx (C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\__init__.pyc)
W: delayed  exec statement detected at line 0 - bdb (C:\Python26\lib\bdb.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - bdb (C:\Python26\lib\bdb.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - bdb (C:\Python26\lib\bdb.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - pickle (C:\Python26\lib\pickle.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - pickle (C:\Python26\lib\pickle.pyc)
W: delayed conditional exec statement detected at line 0 - iu (C:\Python26\pyinstaller-1.3\iu.pyc)
W: delayed conditional exec statement detected at line 0 - iu (C:\Python26\pyinstaller-1.3\iu.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - gettext (C:\Python26\lib\gettext.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - optik.option_parser (C:\Python26\pyinstaller-1.3\optik\option_parser.pyc)
W: delayed conditional eval hack detected at line 0 - warnings (C:\Python26\lib\warnings.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - warnings (C:\Python26\lib\warnings.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - optik (C:\Python26\pyinstaller-1.3\optik\__init__.pyc)
W: delayed  exec statement detected at line 0 - pdb (C:\Python26\lib\pdb.pyc)
W: delayed conditional eval hack detected at line 0 - pdb (C:\Python26\lib\pdb.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - pdb (C:\Python26\lib\pdb.pyc)
W: delayed conditional eval hack detected at line 0 - pdb (C:\Python26\lib\pdb.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - pdb (C:\Python26\lib\pdb.pyc)
```

I don't know what the heck to make of any of that. Again, my searches have been fruitless.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but since you've only written a "hello, world" app in wxPython, I would scrap it and start over with PyQt.  The documentation is better, and the overall end product looks better, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem on the PyInstaller mailing list, and it's remarkably simple, only undocumented.

PyInstaller doesn't yet support Python 2.6. The solution is to get a patch from a page which can now be found in the compilation process that I was trying, if one tries to compile using Python 2.6.

Thanks everyone though!

EDIT: The page used to be hosted at http://svn.pyinstaller.org/branches/py26win but it no longer exists.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have. I've long since forgotten about it by now, though. Thanks for the tip, I'll remember next time.

Comment: There are still people having these problems that would love that link

Answer (score 0):

On windows I have found Py2exe to be more stable and easier to use, have you tried that.